# Check for "ok" response from controller

Tags: php, jquery

I write come code with php, then i convert response in json. How i can check data from this response if ajax function. For example

```
$.ajax({
   method: "POST",
   dataType: "json",
   data: user,
   url: {{ path("indexAction") }}
}).done(function(data){
           if(data['ok']){  // this does not work
              var message = $('#message');
              message.css("background","white");
              message.css("display", "block");
           }
  });
```

If i alert(data) i have such data `{"status":"ok","role":"user"}`. My question is how check my data for status "ok"?

Comment: `if(data.status == "ok")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the returned data is an json object you can check the status like this:

```
if(data.status == "ok") {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `data.status` to access the status. And then

```
if(data.status == 'ok')
```

you can do ur logic

Answer (score 0):

If you just change your

```
if(data['ok']){
```

to

```
if (data["status"] == 'ok')
```

then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace following code:

```
$.ajax({
   method: "POST",
   dataType: "json",
   data: user,
   url: {{ path("indexAction") }}
}).done(function(data){
           if(data.status == 'ok'){  // data['ok'] replace this
              var message = $('#message');
              message.css("background","white");
              message.css("display", "block");
           }
  });
```